# How to fix Pods.sh: line 43 source: unbound variable Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code on Xcode 10.2.1?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, cryptoswift

I'm trying to build and compile my project. It is a heritage from an old coworker which is not longer at the company and I am not that handful on Xcode. Problem is now that I clean and build the project in Xcode, I'm getting a "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code"

[image]

[image]

The project contains the app swift file inside a folder and it is using the cryptoswift library. So I ran using Cocoapods 1.7.4 the creation of pod with the mentioned library at the project's folder and it successfully added Cryptoswift (CryptoSwift (1.0.0) ).

[image]

Comment: Try `pod deintegrate` and `pod update`

Comment: @PaulBeusterien tried this and I get the same error message

Comment: did you resolve that problem?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: getting same any solution?

Comment: getting same issue..

Comment: Try to delete the `VALID_ARCHS` from your project/target and Pod project and clean then rebuild your project.